# How to simulate chain physics (game design)

Tags: actionscript-3, game-physics

I am trying to create a chain of moving objects for a game (AS3). So far, I can drag objects behind another object, but all I can do is make a link move closer to another link based on distance. It doesn't work realistically and it still follows only one direction. If I try to pull the chain the opposite direction, it doesn't work.

I need a formula for pulling a chain behind whatever link is being pulled.

I also need a formula for making the links fall below the rest of the chain when it's at rest. The way I have it set up now, the links try to fall down, but they just fall straight down instead of being pulled below the rest of the chain.

There are a few chain and string tutorials out there, but none of them seem to incorporate gravity or pulling both ways.

[image]

Answer (score 30, accepted):

### Verlet simulation

Your best bet is verlet chain simulation. It incorporates gravity, constraints, and can have forces applied at any point.

In verlet integration (dividing the math into steps) you only store the vertice's current location and the location in the previous frame. Unlike euclidean integration in which you store the current position and the current speed and direction, verlet integration stores the current speed and direction as the difference between positions. This is very well suited to the type of simulation you are after where complex interaction do not have to bother with issues like momentum, rotation and a host of other problems. All you do is remember the last position and set the new, everything else happens automatically.

I will use javascript notation as I have never used actionscript.

---

#### The basics.

The sim starts with points (vertices). A vertex is a free point without size. It has forces of gravity applied per frame and it is constrained by environmental objects like the ground.

The information required to store a vertex

```
vertex = {   
    x : 100, // current position
    y : 100,
    lx : 100,  // last position This point is not moving hence the last pos 
    ly : 100,  // is the same as the current
}
```

For each frame of the animation you apply the various forces to the vertex

**Move point function and some constants**

```
GRAV = 0.9;          // force of gravity
GROUND = 400;        // Y position of the ground. Y is down the screen
GROUND_BOUNCE = 0.5; // Amount of bounce from the ground
DRAG = 0.9;          // Amount of friction or drag to apply per frame

dx = (vertex.x-vertex.lx) * DRAG;  // get the speed and direction as a vector 
dy = (vertex.y-vertex.ly) * DRAG;  // including drag
vertex.lx = vertex.x;   // set the last position to the current
vertex.ly = vertex.y;
vertex.x += dx;         // add the current movement
vertex.y += dy;  
vertex.y += GRAV;       // add the gravity
```

Each frame you also need to apply constraints. They can be almost anything.

For now this will just be the ground. If the position is greater than the ground line then move the point away from the ground. The point may also be fixed (not needing the above movement drag and gravity applied) or fixed to a moving object, like the mouse.

#### Constraining to the ground line.

Because the last position (`vertex.lx`, `vertex.ly`) helps define the current movement. When we change direction (hit the ground) we must change the last position to correctly describe the new direction, this puts the last position under the ground.

**Constrain point function**

```
if(vertex.y > GROUND){
    // we need the current speed
    dx = (vertex.x-vertex.lx) * DRAG;
    dy = (vertex.y-vertex.ly) * DRAG;
    speed = sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy);
    vertex.y = GROUND;  // put the current y on the ground
    vertex.ly = GROUND + dy * GROUND_BOUNCE; // set the last point into the 
                                             // ground and reduce the distance 
                                             // to account for bounce
    vertex.lx += (dy / speed) * vx; // depending on the angle of contact
                                    // reduce the change in x and set 
                                    // the new last x position
 }
```

#### A bunch of points.

That is the basic math for gravity, air friction, and constraints, if we create a point and apply the math it will fall to the ground, bounce a few times and come to a stop.

Because we will need many vertices you create an array of them called for this answer `points`.

Now it is time to connect these points and turn a bunch of free floating vertices into a wide variety of simulated structures.

---

#### The line constraint

For this answer the line represents a link in the chain.

[image]

The above image is to help visualise the concept. A and B are two vertices, the red dots next to them are the last position of the vertices. The red arrow show the approx direction that the vertices will be moved by the line constraint. The length of the line is fixed and the algorithm below attempts to find the best solution that keeps all the lines as close as possible to this length.

#### Describing a line

```
line = {
    pointIndex1 : 0,  // array index of connected point
    pointIndex2 : 1,  // array index of second connected point
    length : 100,  // the length of the line.
    // in the demo below I also include a image index and
    // a draw function 
}
```

A line connects two vertices. A vertex can have many lines connected to it.

Each frame after we apply the movement, drag, gravity, and any other constraints we apply the line constraints. From the image above you can see that the last position of the two vertices were at positions that were too far apart for the line to connect. To fix the line we move both vertices equal amounts towards the center point of the line (red arrows). If the two points were too close for the line length we would move the points apart.

The following is the math used to do this.

**Constrain line function**

```
p1 = points[line.pointIndex1]; // get first point
p2 = points[line.pointIndex2]; // get second point
// get the distance between the points
dx = p2.x - p1.x;
dy = p2.y - p1.y;
distance = sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
// get the fractional distance the points need to move toward or away from center of 
// line to make line length correct
fraction = ((line.length - distance) / distance) / 2;  // divide by 2 as each point moves half the distance to 
                                                       // correct the line length
dx *= fraction;  // convert that fraction to actual amount of movement needed
dy *= fraction;
p1.x -=dx;   // move first point to the position to correct the line length
p1.y -=dy;
p2.x +=dx;   // move the second point in the opposite direction to do the same.
p2.y +=dy;
```

This constraint is very simple and because we are using verlet integration we don't have to worry about the speed and direction of the points, or of the line. Best of all we don't have to deal with any rotation as that is taken care of as well.

---

#### Many points, many lines

At this point we have done all the math needed for a single line, we can add more lines, connecting the end point of the first line to the start of the second line and so on, however long we need the chain. Once we have all the points connected we apply the standard constraints to all the points and then apply the line constraints one by one.

This is where we run into a small problem. When we move the points to correct the length of the first line we move the start point of the next line, then when we move the points for the next line we move the endpoint of the first line breaking its length constraint. When we have gone through all the lines the only line that will have the correct length will be the last one. All the other lines will be pulled slightly toward the last line.

We could leave it as is and that would give the chain a somewhat elastic feel (undesirable in this case but for whips and ropes it works great), we could do a full inverse kinematics end point solution for the line segments (way to hard) or we can cheat. If you apply the line constraint again you move all the points a little more towards the correct solution. We do this again and again, correcting a little for the error introduced in the every previous pass.

This iterative process will move towards a solution but it will never be a perfect, yet we can quickly get to a situation where the error is visually unnoticeable. For convenience I like to call the number of iteration the stiffness of the sim. A value of 1 means the lines are elastic, a value of 10 means there is almost no noticeable stretching of the lines.

**Note** that the longer the chain the more noticeable the stretching becomes and thus the more iterations need to be done to get the required stiffness.

**Note** this method of finding a solution has a flaw. There are many cases where there is more than one solution to the arrangement of points and lines. If there is a lot of movement in the system it may start oscillating between the two (or more) possible solutions. If this happens you should limit the amount of movement a user can add to the system.

---

#### The Main loop.

Putting that all together we need to run the sim once every frame. We have an array of points, and an array of lines connecting the points. We move all the points, then we apply the line constraints. Then render the result ready to do all again next frame.

```
 STIFFNESS = 10; // how much the lines resist stretching
 points.forEach(point => { // for each point in the sim
       move(point); // add gravity drag 
       constrainGround(point); // stop it from going through the ground line
 })
 for(i = 0; i < STIFFNESS; i+= 1){  // number of times to apply line constraint
     lines.forEach(line => { // for each line in the sim
          constrainLine(line);
     })
 }
 drawPoints(); // draw all the points
 drawLines(); // draw all the lines.
```

---

#### Question specific issues

The above method provides a great line simulation, It also does rigid bodies, rag dolls, bridges, boxes, cows, goats, cats, and dogs. By fixing points you can do a variety of hanging ropes and chains, create pulleys, tank tread. Great for simulating 2D cars and bikes. But remember they are all visually acceptable but are not at all a real physics simulation.

You want a chain. To make a chain we need to give the lines some width.  So each vertex needs a radius, and the ground constraint needs to take that into account.  We also want the chain to not fall in on itself so we need a new constraint that prevents balls (AKA vertices) from overlapping each other. This will add quite an extra load to the sim as each ball needs to be tested against each other ball, and as we adjust the position to stop overlap we add error to the line lengths so we need to do each constraint in turn many times to get a good solution per frame.

And the final part is the details of the graphics, Each line needs to have a reference to a image that is a visual representation of the chain.

I will leave all that up to you to work out how best to do in actionscript.

---

#### A demo

The following demo shows the result of all the above. It may not be what you want, and there are other ways to solve the problem. This method has several problems

- Discrete mass, the mass is defined by points, you cant make points lighter or heavier without a lot more math
- Oscillating state. Sometimes the system just starts to oscillate, try to keep movement within a reasonable level.
- Stretching. Though stretching can be almost eliminated there are some situations that the solution will not be perfect. Like an elastic band if a stretch chain is released it will flick. I have not increased the iteration count to match the chain length so the longer chains will show stretching and if you swing it about you will see the chain separate.

The functions you will be interested in are `constrainPoint`, `constrainLine`, `movePoint`, and `doSim` (just the bit after `if(points.length > 0){` in runSim) all the rest is just support and boilerplate.

Best viewed as full page (I made the images a little too big oops... :(

To see the chain click and hold right mouse button to add first block then adds links to the chain. I have not set a limit to the length of the chain. Click and hold the left button to grab and drag any part of the chain and block.

```js
var points = [];
var lines = [];
var pointsStart;
var fric = 0.999; // drag or air friction
var surF = 0.999; // ground and box friction
var grav = 0.9;   // gravity
var ballRad = 10;  // chain radius set as ball radius
var stiffness = 12;  // number of itterations for line constraint
const fontSize = 33;
var chainImages = [new Image(),new Image(),new Image()];
chainImages[0].src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0xqQ.png";
chainImages[1].src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/fv77t.png";
chainImages[2].src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVSqL.png";

// add a point
function addPoint(x,y,vx,vy,rad = 10,fixed = false){
    points.push({
        x:x,
        y:y,
        ox:x-vx,
        oy:y-vy,
        fixed : fixed,
        radius : rad,
    })
    return points[points.length-1];
}
// add a constrained line
function addLine(p1,p2,image){
    lines.push({
        p1,p2,image,
        len : Math.hypot(p1.x - p2.x,p1.y-p2.y),
        draw(){
            if(this.image !== undefined){
                var img = chainImages[this.image];
                var xdx = this.p2.x - this.p1.x;
                var xdy = this.p2.y - this.p1.y;
                var len = Math.hypot(xdx,xdy);
                xdx /= len;
                xdy /= len;
                if(this.image === 2){ // oops block drawn in wrong direction. Fix just rotate here
                                      // also did not like the placement of 
                                      // the block so this line's image
                                      // is centered on the lines endpoint
                    ctx.setTransform(xdx,xdy,-xdy,xdx,this.p2.x, this.p2.y);

                    ctx.rotate(-Math.PI /2);
                }else{
                    ctx.setTransform(xdx,xdy,-xdy,xdx,(this.p1.x + this.p2.x)/2,(this.p1.y + this.p2.y)/2);
                }
                ctx.drawImage(img,-img.width /2,- img.height / 2);
            }
        }
    })   
    return lines[lines.length-1];
}
// Constrain a point to the edge of the canvas
function constrainPoint(p){
    if(p.fixed){
        return;
    }
    var vx = (p.x - p.ox) * fric;
    var vy = (p.y - p.oy) * fric;
    var len = Math.hypot(vx,vy);
    var r = p.radius;
    if(p.y <= r){
        p.y = r;
        p.oy = r + vy * surF;
    }
    if(p.y >= h - r){
        var c = vy / len 
        p.y = h - r
        p.oy = h - r + vy * surF;
        p.ox += c * vx;
    }
    if(p.x < r){
        p.x = r;
        p.ox = r + vx * surF;
    }
    if(p.x > w - r){
        p.x = w - r;
        p.ox = w - r + vx * surF;
    }
}
// move a point 
function movePoint(p){
    if(p.fixed){
        return;
    }
    var vx = (p.x - p.ox) * fric;
    var vy = (p.y - p.oy) * fric;
    p.ox = p.x;
    p.oy = p.y;
    p.x += vx;
    p.y += vy;
    p.y += grav;
}
// move a line's end points constrain the points to the lines length
function constrainLine(l){
    var dx = l.p2.x - l.p1.x;
    var dy = l.p2.y - l.p1.y;
    var ll = Math.hypot(dx,dy);
    var fr = ((l.len - ll) / ll) / 2;
    dx *= fr;
    dy *= fr;
    if(l.p2.fixed){
        if(!l.p1.fixed){
            l.p1.x -=dx * 2;
            l.p1.y -=dy * 2;
        }
    }else if(l.p1.fixed){
        if(!l.p2.fixed){
            l.p2.x +=dx * 2;
            l.p2.y +=dy * 2;
        }
    }else{
        l.p1.x -=dx;
        l.p1.y -=dy;
        l.p2.x +=dx;
        l.p2.y +=dy;
    }
}
// locate the poitn closest to x,y (used for editing)
function closestPoint(x,y){
    var min = 40;
    var index = -2;
    for(var i = 0; i < points.length; i ++){
        var p = points[i];
        var dist = Math.hypot(p.x-x,p.y-y);
        p.mouseDist = dist;
        if(dist < min){
            min = dist;
            index = i;
            
        }
        
    }
    return index;
}

function constrainPoints(){
    for(var i = 0; i < points.length; i ++){
        constrainPoint(points[i]);
    }
}
function movePoints(){
    for(var i = 0; i < points.length; i ++){
        movePoint(points[i]);
    }
}
function constrainLines(){
    for(var i = 0; i < lines.length; i ++){
        constrainLine(lines[i]);
    }
}
function drawLines(){
    // draw back images first
    for(var i = 0; i < lines.length; i ++){
        if(lines[i].image !== 1){
            lines[i].draw();
        }
    }
    for(var i = 0; i < lines.length; i ++){
        if(lines[i].image === 1){
            lines[i].draw();
        }
    }
}
// Adds the block at end of chain
function createBlock(x,y){
    var i = chainImages[2];
    var w = i.width;
    var h = i.height;
    var p1 = addPoint(x,y+16,0,0,8);
    var p2 = addPoint(x-w/2,y+27,0,0,1);
    var p3 = addPoint(x+w/2,y+27,0,0,1);
    var p4 = addPoint(x+w/2,y+h,0,0,1);
    var p5 = addPoint(x-w/2,y+h,0,0,1);
    var p6 = addPoint(x,y+h/2,0,0,1);
    addLine(p1,p2);
    addLine(p1,p3);
    addLine(p1,p4);
    addLine(p1,p5);
    addLine(p1,p6,2);
    addLine(p2,p3);
    addLine(p2,p4);
    addLine(p2,p5);
    addLine(p2,p6);
    addLine(p3,p4);
    addLine(p3,p5);
    addLine(p3,p6);
    addLine(p4,p5);
    addLine(p4,p6);
    addLine(p5,p6);
    var p7 = addPoint(x,y + 16-(chainImages[0].width-ballRad * 2),0,0,ballRad);
    addLine(p1,p7,1);
}
var lastChainLink = 0;
function addChainLink(){
    var lp = points[points.length-1];
    addPoint(lp.x,lp.y-(chainImages[0].width-ballRad*2),0,0,ballRad);
    addLine(points[points.length-2],points[points.length-1],lastChainLink % 2);
    lastChainLink += 1;
}
    
function loading(){
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0)    
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,w,h);
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.fillText("Loading media pleaase wait!!",w/2,30);
    if(chainImages.every(image=>image.complete)){
        doSim = runSim;
    }
}
var onResize = function(){ // called from boilerplate
  blockAttached = false;
  lines.length = 0;  // remove all lines and points.
  points.length = 0; 
  lastChainLink = 0; // controls which chain image to use next
  holdingCount = 0;
  holding = -1;
  mouse.buttonRaw = 0;
}
var blockAttached = false;
var linkAddSpeed = 20;
var linkAddCount = 0;
var holding = -1; // the index of the link the mouse has grabbed
var holdingCount = 0;
function runSim(){
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0)    
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,w,h);
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    if(points.length < 12){
        ctx.fillText("Right mouse button click hold to add chain.",w/2,30);
    }
    if(holdingCount < 180){
        if(mouse.buttonRaw & 1 && holding === -2){
            ctx.fillText("Nothing to grab here.",w/2,66);
        }else{
            ctx.fillText("Left mouse button to grab and move chain.",w/2,66);
        }
    }
    if(mouse.buttonRaw & 4){
        if(linkAddCount > 0){  // delay adding links
            linkAddCount-=1;
        }else{
            if(!blockAttached ){
                createBlock(mouse.x,mouse.y)
                blockAttached = true;
            }else{
                addChainLink(mouse.x,mouse.y);
            }
            linkAddCount = linkAddSpeed;
        }
    }
    if(points.length > 0){
        if(mouse.buttonRaw & 1){
            if(holding < 0){
                holding = closestPoint(mouse.x,mouse.y);
            }
        }else{
            holding = -1;
        }
        movePoints();
        constrainPoints();
        // attach the last link to the mouse
        if(holding > -1){
            var mousehold = points[holding];
            mousehold.ox = mousehold.x = mouse.x;
            mousehold.oy = mousehold.y = mouse.y;
            holdingCount += 1; // used to hide help;
        }
        
        for(var i = 0; i < stiffness; i++){
            constrainLines();
            if(holding > -1){
                mousehold.ox = mousehold.x = mouse.x;
                mousehold.oy = mousehold.y = mouse.y;
            }
        }
        drawLines();
    }else{
        holding = -1;
    }
}

var doSim = loading;

/*********************************************************************************************/
/* Boilerplate not part of answer from here down */
/*********************************************************************************************/
var w, h, cw, ch, canvas, ctx, mouse, globalTime = 0, firstRun = true;
function start(x,y,col,w){ctx.lineWidth = w;ctx.strokeStyle = col;ctx.beginPath();ctx.moveTo(x,y)}
function line(x,y){ctx.lineTo(x,y)}
function end(){ctx.stroke()} 
function drawLine(l) {ctx.lineWidth = 1;ctx.strokeStyle = "Black";ctx.beginPath();ctx.moveTo(l.p1.x,l.p1.y);ctx.lineTo(l.p2.x,l.p2.y); ctx.stroke();}
function drawPoint(p,col = "black", size = 3){ctx.fillStyle = col;ctx.beginPath();ctx.arc(p.x,p.y,size,0,Math.PI * 2);ctx.fill();}

;(function(){
    const RESIZE_DEBOUNCE_TIME = 100;
    var  createCanvas, resizeCanvas, setGlobals, resizeCount = 0;
    createCanvas = function () {
        var c, cs;
        cs = (c = document.createElement("canvas")).style;
        cs.position = "absolute";
        cs.top = cs.left = "0px";
        cs.zIndex = 1000;
        document.body.appendChild(c);
        return c;
    }
    resizeCanvas = function () {
        if (canvas === undefined) {
            canvas = createCanvas();
        }
        canvas.width = innerWidth;
        canvas.height = innerHeight;
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        if (typeof setGlobals === "function") {
            setGlobals();
        }
        if (typeof onResize === "function") {
            if(firstRun){
                onResize();
                firstRun = false;
            }else{
                resizeCount += 1;
                setTimeout(debounceResize, RESIZE_DEBOUNCE_TIME);
            }
        }
    }
    function debounceResize() {
        resizeCount -= 1;
        if (resizeCount <= 0) {
            onResize();
        }
    }
    setGlobals = function () {
        cw = (w = canvas.width) / 2;
        ch = (h = canvas.height) / 2;
        ctx.font = fontSize + "px arial";
        ctx.textAlign = "center";
        ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
        
    }
    mouse = (function () {
        function preventDefault(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        var mouse = {
            x : 0,
            y : 0,
            w : 0,
            buttonRaw : 0,
            over : false,
            bm : [1, 2, 4, 6, 5, 3],
            active : false,
            bounds : null,
            mouseEvents : "mousemove,mousedown,mouseup,mouseout,mouseover,mousewheel,DOMMouseScroll".split(",")
        };
        var m = mouse;
        function mouseMove(e) {
            var t = e.type;
            m.bounds = m.element.getBoundingClientRect();
            m.x = e.pageX - m.bounds.left;
            m.y = e.pageY - m.bounds.top;
            if (t === "mousedown") {
                m.buttonRaw |= m.bm[e.which - 1];
            } else if (t === "mouseup") {
                m.buttonRaw &= m.bm[e.which + 2];
            } else if (t === "mouseout") {
                m.buttonRaw = 0;
                m.over = false;
            } else if (t === "mouseover") {
                m.over = true;
            } else if (t === "mousewheel") {
                m.w = e.wheelDelta;
            } else if (t === "DOMMouseScroll") {
                m.w = -e.detail;
            }
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        m.start = function (element) {
            m.element = element === undefined ? document : element;
            m.mouseEvents.forEach(n => {
                m.element.addEventListener(n, mouseMove);
            });
            m.element.addEventListener("contextmenu", preventDefault, false);
            m.active = true;
        }
        return mouse;
    })();

    function update(timer) { // Main update loop
        doSim(); // call demo code
        requestAnimationFrame(update);
    }
    setTimeout(function(){
        resizeCanvas();
        mouse.start(canvas, true);
        window.addEventListener("resize", resizeCanvas);
        requestAnimationFrame(update);
    },0);
})();
```

#### Images used in demo

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: This is incredible. I'm going to do my best to apply it to my current system if I can. Thanks, man!

Comment: This is very complex for me. Most of my "physics" in the game I've been working on are incredibly simplistic, so I wonder if you might help me bridge the gap between your example and the progress I've made so far. 

So far, I have chain links that move closer together when they are too far apart and I have nodes indicating the "top" and "bottom" of each link, but they aren't being used right now. Gravity is always affecting the chain. 

Based on what I have, what should I do next?

You can see the visual progress I have so far: youtube.com/watch?v=WyD6hhqjsNI&feature=youtu.be –

Comment: @JosephWagner I am a little busy at the moment. To help you get your head around what is happening the following video is a good introduction to verlet integration https://youtu.be/3HjO_RGIjCU its four parts and for javascript but there is very little coding and exelent explanations.

Comment: The demo makes this answer the greatest Verlet tutorial in the internet.

Comment: There is another good link to play with Verlet : http://datagenetics.com/blog/july22018/index.html (good explanation & great demo ; no full code though).   However, this answer is better. Thank a lot, Blindman67.

Answer (score 0):

I would try using [Box2D](http://www.box2dflash.org/). I'm pretty sure once you get the engine up and running you can link objects together to form a "chain" like set. See the demo at the link. Some of the attached bodyparts are "chained" together already.

Comment: I appreciate it, but I'm really looking for some math. I can worry about switching platforms some other time. Also, that link doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Fixed link if you want to check it out.

Comment: Okay, I'm looking over the source code now. Their Bridge example seems to be what I need to learn from, but a more direct formula on tension physics and how it would apply to a chain in a 2D game was more of what I was asking for. Being pointed at a resource that I have to dig through isn't exactly an answer, but maybe this is the best I'll get.